# Disable Power Over HDMI

Tags: power, hdmi, power-supply, alternative-power

I built a Retropie using a **PI Model 3B** that is powered via the GPIO pins. Specifically with [this case](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074DSXF7F) which adapts micro usb to the GPIO power. Everything works fine except when I turn the system off. Once the GPIO power is cut, the system tries to power itself over HDMI. The power coming from HDMI is not enough for the system to boot, so it just starts a never ending loop of boot up then crash.

Is there any way to disable power over HDMI so when I turn the Pi off it stays off? I don't want to have to unplug the HDMI cable every time I turn the system off.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the Pi is powered by HDMI (at least on Pi3)  as there is a Power Switch (RT9741) which produces H5V for HDMI See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Comment: I guess in this forum it's never enough to say "Pi" ... you need to specify which model ...A, B, B+, 2B, 3B, Zero, Zero W ... I'm sure there's more A "flavours" but you get the point

Comment: @JaromandaX My bad. I updated my question. I am using a Pi 3B.

Comment: hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1

Comment: That stops the CEC snatching the source so I'd suggest looking around the /boot/config.txt file for hdmi settings, also maybe CEC.